# What happened to php_mysql.dll?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5

Finally, after hours of strugling, I finished installing PHP 7.02 on our IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008. All functions properly except for one error:

> [20-Jan-2016 15:19:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library
>   'D:\PHP\php-7.0.2-nts-Win32-VC14-x64\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

When checking the downloaded zip-file op PHP 7.02 it's clear that the folder `ext` doesn't contain a file called `php_mysql.dll`.

So my question is where can we get this file to avoid this error?

Comment: mysql_* functions was removed in PHP 7.0 and you can't use it with it

Comment: So there's no way of getting rid of that error? Or maybe removing the `php_mysqli.dll` file from the `ext` folder will do?

Comment: Why remove the `php_mysqli` when  it's the `php_mysql` that's giving you the error..?

Comment: You shouldn't delete `mysqli` because that's the one that replaced `mysql`.  What you should do is make sure that your webserver isn't loading `php_mysql.dll` but `php_mysqli.dll`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Naruto I figured out that the dynamic loading of all the modules in the `php\ext` folder wasn't the culprit. Because the file `php_mysql.dll` wasn't in that folder, so it couldn't be loaded from there. After further analyses it seems that in the latest PHP (7.02) download for Windows 64-bit the `php.ini` file still contains this:

```
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

After commenting out the section the error in the log file was gone. As we obviously can't load that dll file anymore.

```
;[PHP_MYSQL]
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Comment: It looks like for PHP 7.1 there is only one line that needs to be commented out.

Comment: after giving a comment line, still wamp orange color, is any other possibilities of error?

Comment: This worked for me, to install composer.... not the same issue but similar!! upvoting anyway :D it worked!!!

Comment: Still getting this error for an older website after an upgrade to 7.2.10. The line extension=php_mysql.dll does not appear in this php.ini. (The non-deprecated line extension=pdo_mysql does appear. )

Comment: can someone tell me why is this line still there in HP 8.2??

Answer (score 10):

mysql extension was deprecated on v5.5 and removed on v7 please check out link below, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 7.2 when using PDO for MySQL I had to un-comment the following line:

`;extension=pdo_mysql`

`extension=pdo_mysql`

It's worth noting that there are other versions of the PDO extension also commented out:

```
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
```